# How does vuetify color code scheme works?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, colors, vuetify.js, uicolor

I am working on Vuetify.js but I am unable to understand how color code works?

> https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#colors

This is the page I am referring too. This page has some predefined sets of colors, like **red lighten-3 #EF9A9A**

But, if I set my primary color as some random color code like **mediumaquamarine    #66CDAA** and then if I use primary lighten-3, then on what basis does I get my color?

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify calculate color and variants (lighten and darken) based on colors defined on [`theme`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/) at Vuetify inizialation:

```js
new Vuetify({
    theme: {
       themes: {
          light: {
            primary: "#d63fd9", // pink
            secondary: "#b0bec5",
            anchor: "#8c9eff"
         }
       }
    }
})
```

See this codepen with primary color setted pink: https://codepen.io/hans-felix/pen/rNxBemM?editors=1010

Comment: Yes. That's what my question was aimed at. Like on what basis does lighten and darken is defined?
With reference to your example, primary means pink, so primary lighten-3 just means pink with less opacity(alpha value)?

Comment: Yes, in this case Vuetify calc the new color based on amount, you can check the `lighten` and `darken` functions an the end of [utils.ts](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/2db8cc95f9f080c6b6e629894a30865234d26553/packages/vuetify/src/services/theme/utils.ts) on github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, in the `PLUGINS` folder that is inside `src` there is a file called `vuetify.js` there the colors are declared through classes.
in my case I have the file like this

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

import es from 'vuetify/es5/locale/es'

export default new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
    },
    lang: {
        locales: { es },
        current: 'es',
    },
    theme: {
        themes: {
            light: {
                primary: '#621132',
                secondary: '#9d2449',
                accent: '#b38e5d',
                error: '#f44336',
                warning: '#ffeb3b',
                info: '#3f51b5',
                success: '#4caf50'
            },
        },
    },
});
```